# Using a variable inside a method from different classes Java

Tags: java

So in my first class I have

```
     final int[] europeanroulettegame = {0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26};


// random number generated from the roulette

 public static int getRandom(int[] europeanroulette){

     int winningnumber = new Random().nextInt(europeanroulette.length);

     return winningnumber;
 }
```

And in another class I have

```
    public boolean equals(){

    for (int i = 0; i < anyplayer.length; i++) {
        if (winningnumber != anyplayer[i]) {
            return false;
        } 
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I was wondering why this doesn't seem to work? I'm trying to use the winningnumber from the first class, but it doesn't seem to work.

I also want to add that in my driver, I have this

```
    // Dealer announces the winning number (randomly generated)

           int winningnumber = europeanroulette.getRandom(europeanroulettegame); // the name of the first class is europeanroulette
```

I was wondering if the winningnumber generated for my driver would be the same as the one for the equals method?

If not, how do I make sure the same winningnumber is used for both classes and not that one is generated twice (making them different)?

Comment: in your code for equals() i dont see you are passing winning number as parameter.  Also, where this anyplayer coming from ? are they the global variables ? Remember you can access the variables of other class if they are inherited into child class.

Comment: You are hitting false and returning from your for loop on the first equivalence check, you never check more than one element of your array against your winning number, in your for loop only return true if you hit the item, outside of the for loop return false. That will make sure you check against all elements

Comment: Please, please, please use Java naming conventions (variables & methods written in camelCase style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getRandom method does not return a random number from the list. It returns a number between 0 and the length of the list. If you want a random number from the list do:

```
return europeanroulette[(int)(Math.random() * europeanroulette.length)];
```

If you want to get a winning number from your first class into your second. you need to call the method:

```
int winningnumber = europeanroulette.getRandom(europeanroulette.europeanroulettegame);
```

The reason you need to do `europeanroulette.europeanroulettegame` instead of `europeanroulettegame` is that you are referencing a variable in another class.

If you want the same winning number in multiple places then you should save the first winning number you get from `getRandom()` as a global variable.

Or just use this class:

```
class EuropeanRouletteGame{
    static int number;
    static final int range = 37;
    static void newNumber(){
        number = (int)(Math.random() * ranage);
    }
    static int getNumber(){
        return number;
    }
}
```

Use the newNumber method when you want a new random number between 0 and range to be generated. When you call getNumber you will always get the current number.
You should run newNumber before you call getNUmber for the first time because the number is initially zero.

Class names should start with capital letters.

Comment: But is that winningnumber going to be the same as the winningnumber in my driver? Just want to make sure the method isn't executed twice creating two different winningnumbers

Comment: If you only call the method once then it will only happen once. If you call the method in two different places then you will probably get two different numbers.

Comment: I've stored `int winningnumber = europeanroulette.getRandom(europeanroulettegame);` the number in `winningnumber` (this is from my driver), how can I use that number in another method in another class?

Comment: If you"ve stored the number outside of a method(i.e. globally) you can get it by  `DriverClassName.winningnumber`.

Comment: That's what I did! I renamed the int in my driver as eurowinningnumber, used it in my if statement in my other class but it gives me the error `eurowinningnumber cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: I made a class that I think does what you wanted your europeanroulettegame class to do.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to initialize the array at the beginning. You are essentially creating an array of 37 elements (0-36) and returning one number at random. If you need a number in the range [0-36], you can do it in runtime using

```
(int)(new Random().nextInt(37))
```

`Random.nextInt(N)` generates a fraction between 0(inclusive) and N(exclusive). So, casting the return value to integer will give you a range of [0-(N-1)] always, N being integer.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use static exclusively here,

```
import java.util.Random;

public class random {

    static final int[] europeanroulettegame = {0,32,15,19,4,21,2,25,17,34,6,27,13,36,11,30,8,23,10,5,24,16,33,1,20,14,31,9,22,18,29,7,28,12,35,3,26};


// random number generated from the roulette

 public static int getRandom(int[] europeanroulette){   

     int winningnumber = new Random().nextInt(europeanroulette.length);

     return winningnumber;
 }

}



public class randomuse {

    public static boolean eql(int[] anyplayer){
        boolean present = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < anyplayer.length; i++) {

            if (new random().getRandom(anyplayer) != anyplayer[i]) {
                present=false;  } 
            else {  present= true; }
        }

            return present;
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(eql(random.europeanroulettegame));
    }

}
```